# Create object from stream of objects keyed by a property in jq

Tags: json, jq

This is a question about the command line json processor [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/). It is *not* about javascript or jQuery or anything else with js and qs in its name :-)

I have input data like:

```
{ "id": "person1", "name": "wilma", "age": "quite old"}
{ "id": "person2", "name": "fred"}
{ "id": "person1", "name": "betty", "x": "extra"}
```

I want output like this:

```
{
   "person1": { "name": "betty", "age": "quite old", "x": "extra" },
   "person2": { "name": "fred" }
}
```

I have tried various things!

e.g.

```
jq -s '.[] | { (.id) : . }' <data
```

gives

```
{ "person1": { "id": "person1", "name": "wilma", "age": "quite old" }}
{ "person2": { "id": "person2", "name": "fred" }}
{ "person1": { "id": "person1", "name": "betty", "x": "extra" }}
```

Which is sort of there, except it's outputting a stream of objects instead of just one. I need to merge all those objects together.

[jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/_g2-njf8GS)

I've also tried using `group_by(.id)[]|add` which merges each item but still results in a stream. https://jqplay.org/s/lh6QUQ0DO4

Comment: The JSON provided isn't valid syntactically. Can you post your script in JSON lint - https://jsonlint.com/ and fix it/

Comment: @Inian Pretty sure it is valid - it's not a json object, it's a json stream - which is why I'm using JQ's `-s` option. Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2):

You could tweak your attempt as follows:

```
jq -s 'map({ (.id) : . }) | add' <data
```

However, it would be more efficient to use `inputs` and `reduce` with the -n command-line option instead of -s.

Of course, using this approach runs the risk of collisions.

You might also want to add `del(.id)`

Comment: This seems to lose `age`.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for the caveat.

Comment: Ah, got you. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! I've got it! Or I've got one solution - please post if there's a better way.

```
jq -s '[group_by(.id)[]| add | { (.id) : . } ]|add' <data
```

https://jqplay.org/s/BfAdRBZUMW

1. `group_by` groups the inputs by their `.id` value and produces an array of arrays - the inner arrays are the values that match on id.
2. for each group the inner arrays are passed to `add` which, because the things in the inner arrays are objects, merges them.
3. That leaves a 2 item array. We feed that to an object constructor which plucks the `id` as the key and the whole item as the value. This still leaves an array of items.
4. the outer `[]` (starts at start of pattern) says take all those and feed it to `add` (again), which merges the final objects created in (3).

It works, but there may be a cleaner way.

### EDIT

This is uglier but produces the same result and is ~24% faster on a 9MB dataset.

```
jq -s 'reduce [.[]|{ (.id) : . }][] as $item ({}; . * $item )' <data
```

This uses [`reduce <list> as <$var> (<initiation>; <iteration>)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Reduce) starting with an empty object `{}` and using the merge operator `*` starting from the incoming item `.` to create the output. I'm surprised it's faster, but I understand that `group_by` does a sort, so I guess that's an additional time cost.